# Template ctor mssing

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I assume the answer will be simple, but I cannot figure out a solution.

I have a class to be used as an interface in the h-file:

```
template <typename T>
class MyInterface
{
public:
  MyInterface();
};
```

In the cpp-file it is:

```
#include "MyInterface.h"
template<typename T>
MyInterface<T>::MyInterface()
{
}
```

My class using the interface is:

```
class Test : MyInterface<int>
{
};
```

When compiling I get the error, the ctor of MyInterace is not declared.

unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyInterface::MyInterface(void)" (??0?$MyInterface@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Test::Test(void)"

Having the ctor declared in the h-file, it compiles.

Comment: Can someone answer please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

Templates are instantiated on the fly. If you want to put the constructor in a `cpp` file, you must specialize it.

```
#include "MyInterface.h"
template<>
MyInterface<int>::MyInterface()
{
}
```

Otherwise, it must be in a header as all template functions are managed inline.

If you'd like to keep code organized, make an `inl` file, with all the function bodies of your code, and then include it at the bottom of your header.

```
// MyInterface.h
template <typename T>
class MyInterface
{
public:
  MyInterface();
};

#include "MyInterface.inl"
```

```
// MyInterface.inl
template<class T>
MyInterface<T>::MyInterface()
{
}
```